# multiple xla files in xlstart folder, can't see macro in the list

Tags: vba, excel

I've already had an XLA file in my *c:\Users\myusrname\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART* folder, and that one is working fine. Let's call this one "**previous.XLA**"

Now I've created another one, let's call it "**newOne.xla**". I also want to use its macros frequently, so it would be nice to be able to call them by pressing Alt+F8. However, only the macros from "previous.XLA" are listed.

The strange thing is that if I close Excel, re-start it and go into the macro editor (by pressing Alt+F11), the newOne is there.

Do anybody know what can be wrong? How can I have my new macros in the macro list too?

Many thanks in advance for your kind help!

Answer (score 0):

it is not enought just to put `.xla` or `.xlam` in folder, you need to connect to it using addins.

Go to `Excel Options` ~>`Add-ins` ~> in window bottom you will see `Manage: [Excel Add-ins]` click `Go...` ~> in appeared window click `Browse` ~> click on required `.xla` and press `ok`. then again go to `Excel Options` ~> `Customize` ~> at the top of the window you will see selection screen `Choose comand from:`, select `Macros` ~> `Add >>`. Then you can modify icon for the macros using `Modify...` button and press `OK`. 
selected macros will be available `quick access toolbar`

**quick access toolbar**

[image]

**project explorer**

[image]

Comment: almost, good as workaround, but what I meant is not the quick access toolbar, but to have it in the macro list by pressing Alt+F8

Comment: to be more specific, this is the window where I would like to have my macros in the newOne.xla ---->
in excel 2013 you find it on the Developer tab > Code > Macros:
http://www.ulearnoffice.com/imagesoffice2003/excel-macro7.gif

Comment: it seems that previous your file with extention  `.xla` is not actually belongs to addins, I guess that it was saved as `.xls` and then extention of the file has been changed from `.xls` to `.xla`. maybe I'm wrong, but I never seen that macros from addins were listed as available macros due to addins is not workbook. So, if you will save your workbook as `.xls` and then replace extention of the file, then you can display the macro through `alt+f8`, but this is not standard way to use `.xla`. I am aslo using an addins, but through variant which described in my answer.

Comment: with described way in my answer, you can create userform with buttons for launch different macroses, also shortcut keys can be used for calling macroses, but this up to you of course